# Unable to break items within dictionary in AWS Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I am trying to parse AWS Cloudwatch logs, which has error logs as follows

```
[ERROR] timestamp requestID message1 {'A', 'B', 'C'} message2. 
[ERROR] timestamp requestID message1 {'A'} message2. 
[ERROR] timestamp requestID message1 {'A'} message2. 
[ERROR] timestamp requestID message1 {'B', 'A'} message2.
```

I want to read the items inside dictionary and create a count plot on it.
If the item count is 1, I am able to use the following parsing query, however it breaks when I have more than 1 item

```
filter @message like /ERROR/
| parse "message1 {*}" as type
| stats count() as count by type
```

I get the output as

```
item             count
'A', 'B', 'C'  -    1
'A'            -    2
'B', 'A'       -    1
```

Desired was

```
'A' - 4
'B' - 2
'C' - 1
```

I am not sure how to break the dictionary and get the count on it